# Fixed width on IE8 doesn't work

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with fixed width on an website. I need to make it work on IE8 and I don't know what to do.

This is my code:

[image]

And here is the tables styles that is rendering:

[image]

This is the page I am talking about: http://www.bayercropscience.ro/fidelis/magazin (I run Win XP with IE8 on a virtual machine to test it).

Comment: see if this works :  table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

Comment: @Vaibhav Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the layout issue is because some of your images are very wide:
http://awards.createdirect.ro/cache/images/HQ6906_16.jpg-800x600

It seems IE 8 is basing the first column width on the largest image without taking the inline `max-width` style into account first. As @Vaibhav suggested, adding `table-layout: fixed;` tells the browser to base the column widths on the first row only, which is why it fixes the issue.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Another solution would be to manually resize your images to be 60px wide, which would also be better for performance ;)

Additionally, I noticed an issue with this select element: `<select class="select2 search_input">`.

By default, a select list will be as wide as its longest `<option>` value, which in your case *very* long:

`Tableta ASUS Transformer Book T100TA-DK005H (Intel Atom Quad-Core Z3740, 10.1" Multi-Touch, 2GB RAM, 500GB + 32GB eMMC, USB 3.0, microHDMI, Windows 8.1, Licenta Full Office Home & Student 2013, 2 Ani Garantie)`

This causes the select to be really wide, triggering horizontal scroll bars in the browser. It can be fixed by simply adding `width: 100%;` to `.search_input`.

This is only noticeable in IE 8 because the Select2 plugin isn’t running due some JS errors.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I already fixed that errors with Select2 and the other ones using IE conditional statements (different css + jquery version). Now it looks greate. I just needed to make my tabled take the fixed width so I can work on it. The site is kinda old and until we will remake it we won't work on it anymore.